# Biased Parameter Estimation in Poisson Regression

Tags: regression, poisson-regression, overdispersion

I read over here (https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/5.0040330) that *"If the equi-dispersion is not met, the Poisson Regression is no longer appropriate to model the data. Moreover, the resulted model will yield biased parameter estimation and underestimate the standard error".*

I have taken some intro courses in statistics and learned about "biasedness". I believe that biasedness means that the expected value of a variable subtracted from the variable itself is equal to 0.

As for the above quote, can someone please try to explain the logic behind this statement? How can we know that if equi-dispersion is not met, the Poisson Regression model will always result in biased parameter estimation and underestimate the standard error? Is this just a logical conclusion or is there actually some way to demonstrate this?

Comment: The paper you linked is about *overdispersion*, there are many relevant posts on this site, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175875/checking-for-overdispersion-in-a-poisson-model and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554622/meaning-of-overdispersion-in-statistics.  The quote you give is imprecise, the last part is true, the first not necessarily.

Comment: "I believe that biasedness means that the expected value of a variable subtracted from the variable itself is equal to 0." --- the  second half of that is defining unbiasedness, not biasedness.

Comment: do you know why the last part is true?

Comment: @MBA_Grad_Student_2022: "do you know why the last part is true?" Yes, if you calculate standard errors based on the Poisson model, but the dispersion is really larger, then of course the SE's becomes to small.

Comment: @ Kjetil: is there some link that shows the logic of this? if the overdispersion is large, shouldn't the SE (Standard Errors) also be large?